# CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync for windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, certificate

I am trying to import my certificate using `CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync` API but it does not complete successfully. When I try and catch any exception occurred, surprisingly, it does not throw any exception either. My client is Windows Phone 8.1 (runtime).

Code:

```
await CertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(stringDataBase64Encoded,
                    stringPassword, ExportOption.NotExportable,
                    KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent, InstallOptions.None, stringFriendlyName);
```

In simple words, when I press F10 on this line of code, it goes into some infinitely time taking process.

Edit: Also, it would help if I can check the directory in WP where the certificates are stored. Like in Windows we have them stored in the local storage "/AppData\Local\Packages\\AC\Microsoft\SystemCertificates\My\Certificates" folder.